# How can I host a map service that uses an online basemap as well as my own dynamic layers?

Tags: arcgis-server, printing, online, mashup, web-service

I have a flex web application with an ArcGIS Server backend that I want to start using an online basemap for.  The application includes a printing capability that prints a layout from an arcGIS map service.  If I use an online basemap, as well as our own local dynamic layers in the application, then how can I create a print layout that includes all of those layers?

I attempted something similar to this a couple years ago, but it didn't work and these knowledge base links indicate that it's a bad idea:

http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=35903

http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=34552

Is there no way to print a layout that includes the multiple services used by the application?

The reason the mashup needs to happen on the server is that the printed map is in a layout which includes legend, north arrow, scale bar, etc.  simply grabbing several map images and overlaying them would be fine if not for the need for marginalia.

I'll try to be more specific:

Our users see a base map as well as several client-specific data layers overlayed.  They have the ability to turn their data layers on and off.  At any point, they can request a layout to be saved as an image, or sent directly to a printer.  The layout should contain all of the layers they see in the map (basemap and data layers) as well as some marginalia.  The user does not have control over the marginalia, however the application administrator needs to be able to modify the layouts/marginalia by editing the mxd in arcmap.

So, what I need to do is either be able to cascade services in order to host the print layout service in arcgis server, or I need a way to propagate marginalia from an mxd to the flex client for printing.  I haven't looked into the second option, but I'm guessing it's a no-go.

Comment: Do you have more info describing the strategy used for printing?

Comment: At the end of the day, a map from server is just a bunch of images slapped on top of one another (with alpha, of course) and sent to the printer. If you can find a way to extract each layer as an image, you can then recomposite them and pump them out to a printer. [Here](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16697) is an example via Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

I have used FlexPrintJob class to create a print out for my Applicatione. These used multiple Map services & created expected Results.

I can't share that Code here, but I would be glad to help you if you have any specific problems.